# difference between sending int or char to /dev/audio (in Linux)

Tags: c, linux, audio

I have this small C program (play.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int t;
  for (t=0; t<8000; t++) {
    printf ("%c", t%256);
  }
}
```

when I redirect it's output (in Linux):

```
./play > /dev/audio
```

it plays a sound as I expect. But if I format the output in `printf` as int (`%d`) instead of char, I get a different sound (and a wrong one, as far as my ears are telling me).

Why does that happen? Aren't the same numbers are sent to the audio device?

Comment: Try running your program _without_ redirecting. You'll see pretty clearly what is going on.

Comment: Of course I did it, but I get either ints (0,1,2,...) or characters. How does that help me?

Comment: Well, if what you see is different, why are you expecting this to make the same sound? Different input should generate different output, no?

Comment: But /dev/audio interprets its input as 8 bit audio samples, so I thought it 'casts' the input - I didn't expect a difference between int and char.

Comment: No, as you say, it interprets it as 8 bit samples. If you `print("0");`, the data received by the device is `0x30`. If you `printf("%c", (char)0);`, the data received is `0x00`.

Comment: @ItamarKatz: How should `/dev/audio` guess if `0123456012` is a byte sequence (0x30,0x31,...) or the decimal representation of three ints (0, 12345, 6012)?

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. I know It's very basic, but it still got me confused.

Comment: @Mat, so isn't `printf("%d",0);` also sends `0x00`? Or actually it sends the whole 4 bytes.

Comment: @ItamarKatz: No! That prints the string "0", ascii 0x30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as `man printf` would tell you, or a simple diff on the output redirected into two files. '%c' prints the unsigned char part (the first 8 bits) as one character, and '%d' the whole number in base-10 digit representation.